# XmlWriter can't write directly to a URL, so how should I send XML to a URL?

Tags: xml, vb.net

As the question states, I've tried to use `XmlWriter` with a target defined as an http address which is associated with a shared documents site. How would I send a file there using `XmlWriter`or otherwise not using `XmlWriter`?

```
    Dim resolver As XmlUrlResolver = New XmlUrlResolver()
    resolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    doc.XmlResolver = resolver

    Dim feedWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("URL")

    Select Case format
        Case FeedFormats.Atom
            Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml"

            Dim atomFormatter As New Atom10FeedFormatter(feed)
            atomFormatter.WriteTo(feedWriter)
        Case FeedFormats.Rss
            Response.ContentType = "application/atom+xml"

            Dim rssFormatter As New Rss20FeedFormatter(feed)
            rssFormatter.WriteTo(feedWriter)
    End Select

    doc.Save(feedWriter)

    feedWriter.Close()
```

This is a snippet, I haven't added my declaration of the cases or feed, but that is unnecessary. I suppose this should be done with output streams, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Consider using `WebRequest`

Comment: Any further context of how I would do this using XMLWriter? I am looking over the MSDN documentation and I am confused how I would use WebRequest with XML Data

Comment: You would first of all need to learn what this "shared documents site" wants in terms of the HTTP protocol. This is not transparent. In other words, there's no such thing as "write to a URL".

Comment: I'll try both get and post, after that, what would I do? I'm not looking for a step by step here, just a little guidance in terms of how you would suggest I use web request and convert the XMLWriter into a binary stream

Comment: Why do you want a "binary stream"?

Comment: I don't, you said use WebRequest, which invokes a binary stream as far as I read on MSDN, and I asked you to be a little more specific please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30939/discussion-between-jcg-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is totally untested:

```
Public Sub WriteXmlToUrl(url As Uri)
    Dim request AS HttpWebRequest = CTYPE(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/xml"
    Using stream = request.GetRequestStream
        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream)
            rem Write your Xml
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you. I'll modify that a little if need be and edit it to what works if necessary.

Comment: How do I execute this code once I have written my XML to the XmlWriter? I need to stream.Write, or somehow tell the stream to execute the stream to do something.

Comment: No. XmlWriter will write to the stream for you.